# Open circuit test of a single phase transformer

Tags: transformer

In open circuit test of a transrormer, 
will the values of the parameters be different if we perform the test on the high voltage side and then we perform the test on the low voltage side ?

Comment: this looks like school work ... what do you believe to be the answer and why?

Comment: I believe that the parameters values should be different because the core losses should be the same whether we perform the test on the secondary or primary ,and that can be achieved if the parameters has changed for each test

Comment: I am taking this course by myself

Comment: Are the "parameters"  colour, smell, niceness and sincerity? :-) || IF NOT then please explain WHAT parameters that you are seeking to measure. | Primary and secondary inductances (usually) differ.  So too many other parameters which are often related by the turns ration or the square of the ratio or ...

Comment: It is a very clear question if you ever read about open circuit test. The parameters an open circuit measures are the magnetizing reactance , energy component of current , magnetizing component of current etc .

Answer (score 0):

Under open circuit test, in a sense, the transformer is no longer a transformer, but a pure inductor. The inductance is proportional to the N^2. So measuring from primary side (higher voltage and higher N in your case), you will see higher inductance, less magnetizing current. From the other side, you will get less inductance and higher current.